# updading json and Grouping json in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json in the following format, its a file stored in a location.

```
{"click_id": 123, "created_at": "2016-10-03T10:50:33", "product_id": 98373, "product_price": 220.50, "user_id": 1, "ip": "10.10.10.10"}
{"click_id": 124, "created_at": "2017-02-03T10:51:33", "product_id": 97373, "product_price": 320.50, "user_id": 1, "ip": "10.10.10.10"}
{"click_id": 125, "created_at": "2017-10-03T10:52:33", "product_id": 96373, "product_price": 20.50, "user_id": 1, "ip": "192.168.2.1"}
```

I want to know how to aggregate the json data in python.
For instance : I need to take the sum of `product_price` grouped by `User_Id and IP`

Comment: That isn't valid json, it's perhaps ndjson, separated by newlines. What have you tried? There's tonnes of questions/answers already on how to process json but you've shown no effort on your part.

Comment: @roganjosh I tried using data = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.textFile("myfile.json").map(lambda l: l.split(':')),
    ["clickid","createdat","productid","productprice","userid","ip"] but this doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: post your actual `"myfile.json"`

Comment: Please post your code as an edit into the initial question, not as a comment

Answer (score 0):

If your initial file is just a text file with *JSON* string on each separate line - use the following solution:

```
import json, collections

with open('myfile.json', 'r') as f:
    result = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for d in map(json.loads, f):
        result[str(d['user_id']) +','+ d['ip']] += d['product_price']
    for k,sum in result.items():
        print('user_id: {}, ip: {}, sum: {}'.format(*k.split(','), sum))
```

The exemplary output:

```
user_id: 1, ip: 10.10.10.10, sum: 541.0
user_id: 1, ip: 192.168.2.1, sum: 20.5
```